# arangodb two degree friend recommendation

Tags: arangodb, recommendation-engine

I have a set of vertexes and a set of edges to make a graph,The format of the side is as follows:[image]

I want to ask for a two degree friend recommendation of a specified point,recommended friends are the first N of the second - tier relationship,Do you have an algorithm for this recommendation?My data is very big, I hope it's efficient.

Comment: If you say first N, can it be any N vertices at depth 2 from starting point S, or is there any order requirement? Like the alphabetically first N?

Comment: My requirement for N is the descending ranking of the count of the second-level vertices that contact the first-level vertices,@CoDEmanX